# Day code in jMeter into variable

Tags: date, formatting, jmeter

Is it possible to get code of current day in jMeter into variable? Day code I mean something like: MON or FRI or something like that. I need do get it into variable and work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use BSF processors and if you used Groovy then it would look like `Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2011-04-02").format("EEE")`. This produces three letter code of day. E.g., today is "Tue". Then you can use `toUpperCase()` to make it TUE.

Comment: I used this:
x = new java.util.Date()
println x
y = x.format("EEE").toUpperCase()
println y
And output is: Tue Feb 04 13:13:18 CET 2014
┌T
second line is in my czech locale (with bad first char - should be Ú)

Comment: But in variable is correctly "ÚT" instead of "┌T". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using the jmeter time function can help here. `${__time(E,)}` will return the current day in short format, i.e `Mon`, `Tue`, `Wed`. If you're looking for a longer format, `${__time(EEEE,)}` will return the current day in long format, i.e `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`. Hope this helps.